# Отслеживание прокрутки WebView

Tags: android, webview, прокрутка

Как мне отследить положение прокрутки в `WebView` и получить его, чтобы записать, например, в базу, а потом подгрузить его и применить к странице (чтобы страница прокрутилась до этого места)?

На вопрос, для чего это нужно, отвечу:

1. Например, запоминать положение прокрутки и менять его при изменении ориентации
2. Запоминать, до какого места пользователь пролистал страницу и переходить к этому месту при повторном открытии
   Для `TextViev` это вроде как несложно, но нужно именно для `WebView`.

**Добавлено**:

В крайнем случае, если это невозможно для `WebView`, как это сделать для `ScrollView` (я бы просто поместил свой `WebView` в него)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У `WebView` есть защищенный метод [onScrollChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#onScrollChanged(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)), доступный только в наследуемых от `WebView` классах.

Простой пример:

```java
    private int scrollPosition = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        scrollPosition = prefs.getInt("scroll", 0);

        WebView myWebView = new WebView(this) {
            @Override
            protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
                super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
                scrollPosition = t;
            }
        };

        // ...

        setContentView(myWebView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("scroll", scrollPosition);
        editor.commit();
    }
```