# Как узнать текущее положение контента в webview и установить эту позицию?

Tags: java, android

Есть Activity в котором webwiew и в него загружена страница. При просмотре страницы происходит сдвиг "ползунка" на какую-то позицию n.

Как при загрузке этой страницы повторно, сразу установить "ползунок" в нужную позицию (n)?

Comment: Возможно [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855715) найдете ответ.

Comment: Посмотрите эти ответы, может помогут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1059202/195483 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1059029/195483